# How to filter null values in ArrayList

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I have a very big code. I faced an issue where at very starting of code, null 
 gets inserted inside arraylist `custlist` i.e custlist looks like [null]. And after many lines of code, I had my code changes where I was building up Predicate using `custlist` as shown below:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Customer> q = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);

Root<Customer> root = q.from(Customer.class);
q.select(root);
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(custlist)){
Predicate predicate1 =root.get("custid").in(custlist);
}

q.where(predicate1);
TypedQuery<Customer> tq = em.createQuery(q);
List<Customer> allcust= tq.getResultList();
```

So the first check gets passed since `(custlist != null && !custlist.isEmpty())`
and predicate was built up. This gave me error when final query is being executed.My question is - is there anyway by which I can make sure that predicate is only created when custlist doesn't have null values.
My ask is - Just like Collectionutils.isEmpty() makes a check for null & emptyness simultaneously , if anyone can help me with some API that can also check `null inside arraylist` as well.

Comment: what is the final query? `This gave me error when final query is being executed`

Comment: Select * from cust_table where custid in (?)

Comment: show the error message and this code is not sufficient

Comment: Please add more code and clarify your issue.

Comment: What is your final query that is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Jesse I have added more code

Comment: @Sibgha Select * from cust_table where custid in (?)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @shmosel My question is - is there anyway by which I can make sure that predicate is only created when custlist doesn't have null values.

Comment: Yes.  Before you create the predicate, iterate over `custlist` and look for any `null` values.  If you find any, don't create the predicate.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes that is an obvious choice but I am looking for any method which can do the same thing in one go.(Just like Collectionutils.isEmpty() makes a check for null & emptyness simultaneously , if some API can also check null inside arraylist as well)

Comment: you can try this : if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(custlist) && !custlist.contains(null)){

Comment: @JulienMaret Thanks  man !!! this is what I wanted !! Can you write this in anwer so that I can accept as your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a generic solution :

```
private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    list.add("foo");
    list.add("bar");
    if (!list.isEmpty() && !list.contains(null))
        System.out.println("ok");
    list.add(null);
    if (!list.isEmpty() && !list.contains(null))
        System.out.println("not ok");
}
```

result

```
ok
```

Comment: A solution which is elegant in its simplicity !

Answer (score 1):

using the stream would look like

```
myList.stream().filter(x-> x!=null).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Yes we can also use this approach as well